# How to do testing of insert function that inserts data to mysql using mock object?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpunit

I have gone through different stack overflow post on how to do  phpunit test for insert or update function using mock object but none of them solved my problem as they were  not clear.

I have a class named DatabaseTable with function below

```
class DatabaseTable
{
public $table;
function __construct($table)
{
    $this->table=$table;
}
function insert($record) {
global $pdo;
$keys = array_keys($record);

$values = implode(', ', $keys);
$valuesWithColon = implode(', :', $keys);

$query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' (' . $values . ') VALUES (:' . 
 $valuesWithColon . ')';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute($record);
}
```

And Test Class as

```
<?php 
require 'classes/databasetable.php';
class savedataTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

 public function testValidData() {

 $validData = [
 'firstname' => 'John',
 'lastname' => 'Smith',
 'email' => 'john@example.org'
 ];
 $this= 'abc';
 $users = $this->getMockBuilder('DatabaseTable')->getMock();
 $users->expects($this->once())
 ->method('insert')
 ->with($this->equalTo($validData));
 $valid = insert($validData);
 $this->assertTrue($valid);
 }
}
```

I got an error " Too few arguments to function DatabaseTable::__construct(), 0 passed" . Can anybody help me in writing a test class?

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate error problem is solved by disabling the constructor in your mock object.

```
$users = $this->getMockBuilder('DatabaseTable')
              ->disableOriginalConstructor()
              ->getMock();
```

However, I'm more concerned that your test doesn't seem to actually test anything useful. You have a data set that you've created within the test, and then pass that data to a mock with a no-op `insert` method that you also created in the same test. This doesn't actually verify the functionality of any code that isn't part of the test itself.

If your goal here is to test the DatabaseTable class, then your actual mock boundary is the PDO object, and you want to check that the DatabaseTable class is actually calling `prepare` and `execute` correctly.

```
<?php

require 'classes/DatabaseTable.php';

class savedataTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testValidData()
    {
        $validData = [
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Smith',
            'email' => 'john@example.org'
        ];
        $table = 'users';

        $stmt = $this->createMock('PDOStatement');
        $stmt->expects($this->once())
            ->method('execute')
            ->with($validData)
            ->willReturn(true);

        global $pdo;
        $pdo = $this->createMock('PDO');
        $pdo->expects($this->once())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->with("INSERT INTO {$table} (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)")
            ->willReturn($stmt);

        $users = new DatabaseTable($table);
        $users->insert($validData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to test the DatabaseTable class as you have said. But I have no clue how to test that. 
I was able to test other functions that were not associated with database connection. But I am having a problem in testing DatabaseTable class .

Could you please elaborate on how to do testing whether the class is calling prepare or execute.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: @DamodarBhattarai I have edited the response with a test that mocks the PDO object. You can have your mock methods return values using `willReturn`. In this case you want the mock `prepare` method to return a second mock of the statement handle in order to verify `execute`.